# AttributeError: 'BinaryRelevance' object has no attribute 'classifiers'

Tags: python, scikit-multilearn

I'm trying to classify datas (emotions) using BinaryRelevance and SVC. This code is in

> http://scikit.ml/tutorial.html

```
from skmultilearn.dataset import load_dataset
X_train, y_train, feature_names, label_names = load_dataset('emotions', 'train')
X_test, y_test, _, _ = load_dataset('emotions', 'test')
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = BinaryRelevance(
    classifier=SVC(),
    require_dense=[False, True]
)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.classifiers
```

and I have this problem

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-5aa82f5c3cc2> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.classifiers

AttributeError: 'BinaryRelevance' object has no attribute 'classifiers'
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is a bit outdated, if you type `clf.classifiers_` instead it should work.